# getting error when installing new-doc plugin in grails

Tags: grails

I am getting failed download error when trying to install new-doc plugin. The error message I get looks like:

```
    ==== http://repo.grails.org/grails/libs-releases-local: tried

      http://repo.grails.org/grails/libs-releases-local/net/sf/json-lib/json
-lib/2.4/json-lib-2.4.jar

            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

            ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::

            :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::

            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

            :: net.sf.json-lib#json-lib;2.4!json-lib.jar

            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


| Error Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):

- net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:2.4
```

My BuildConfig.groovy looks like:

```
grails.servlet.version = "3.0" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.plugins.dir = "plugins"

grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}.war"
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
// inherit Grails' default dependencies
inherits("global") {
    // uncomment to disable ehcache
    // excludes 'ehcache'
}
log "warn" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
repositories {
    grailsPlugins()
    grailsHome()
    grailsCentral()

    // uncomment the below to enable remote dependency resolution
    // from public Maven repositories
    //mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    //mavenRepo "http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org"
    //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
    //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
    //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
}
dependencies {
    // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes eg.

    compile 'org.apache.poi:poi:3.9'
    compile 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.9'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:12.0'

}
plugins {
    compile ":new-doc:0.3.2"
}
}
```

I am fairly new to groovy/grails so I am not sure what should I do next to resolve this issue. Or can anyone suggest me any other code documentation plugin for grails?

Thanks,
Dee

**NOTE** 
When I ran "grails doc" it generated all the documentation code in target/docs folder. It has index.html page which I thought would list all the api functions, but it didn't have any information on the api documents there - so I wrongly concluded that grails doc was not generating the API documentation. I should have looked into target/docs/gapi folder instead to get the generated API documents for grails. I apologize for my noob problem, and not being able to see the solution that was right there in front of me. Thanks.

Comment: When you say install-plugin what does that mean? I see you already added the entry to BuildConfig, are you trying to run `install-plugin` command explicitly? Have you also tried a `grails clean` then `grails compile`?

Comment: Yeah, initially I tried to install the plugin using the command line, that didn't work. Then later I found out the proper way to do things is to add the dependency in the config file. I added the dependency in config file and then did a clean compile but I am still facing the same issue.

Comment: What version of Grails? This is for 1.x projects, but you don't need it for 2.x projects since the functionality is already there

Comment: Yup you are right, i am using ver 2.3.3 of grails. Probably grails doc is what i need but at this moment I am not sure if thats what I am looking for since it doesnt seem to read comments from the code itself.

Comment: I apologize for this question. Groovy doc does generate the documentation out of the code comments - it does so in target/docs/gapi folder. I was opening target/docs/index.html which basically contained no information on the api so I thought that the api doc is not getting generated.